# How to prove that homometric sets lead to same result in this problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

First  let me define *Difference multiset* for a set of integers 
$$P=\{p_1,p_2, \dots,p_K\} ,\quad p_i \in\{1,2,\dots,N\},\quad p_i\ne p_j
$$
as below:
$$
D = \{p_i-p_j \mod N ,\quad i \ne j\}
$$
I know that the minimum of $f(x)$ is same for all $P$'s having same difference multiset (homometric $P$'s) & and also the optimal $x$ (minimizing $f$) is same for all of them up to permutation of elements, (also for all homometric $P$'s same $l$ is the inner maximizer) , where $f(x)$ is a real function which is defined as:

> $$\large
> f(x) = \max_{1 \leq l \leq N-1}
> {\sum_{j=1}^K \sum_{k=1}^K x_j x_k e^{\frac{i2\pi l(p_j-p_k)}N} \over \left( \sum_{i=1}^K x_i\right)^2 } = \max_{1 \leq l \leq N-1}
> { \sum_{i=1}^K x_i^2 + \sum_{j,k} x_j x_k cos(\frac{2\pi l(p_j-p_k)}N) \over \left( \sum_{i=1}^K x_i\right)^2 }
> $$
>   $x_i$'s are positive variables

I achieved this result from simulations. I'm looking for a proof or even a justification which helps me prove it.

Let me give you an example of my simulations if it helps:

suppose $(N,K)= (6, 4)$

$$
P = \{1,2,3,5\} \Rightarrow D = \{1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5\}
$$
minimizing $f(x)$ with $p_i$'s being members of $P$, led to this $x=(4,5,4,4)$

and for 
$$
P' = \{1,2,4,6\} \Rightarrow D' = \{1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5\} = D
$$
minimizing $f(x)$ with $p_i$'s being members of $P'$, led to this $x=(5,4,4,4)$

Also note that $f(x) $ is independent of $||x||_2$ and is just function of angle of vector $x$.

I've also asked this on [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450065/how-to-prove-that-homometric-sets-lead-to-same-result-in-this-problem-any-just)

Comment: May I suggest replacing the title with a more informative and descriptive one? That may attract more people who may be able to give you an answer.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade I did it. Is it OK now?

Comment: crossposted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450065/how-to-show-this-even-a-justification-would-be-helpful

Comment: @Mahdi: I apologize for being unclear before. My suggestion was to briefly describe your particular problem (i.e *what* you want to show) in the title. That could give people an idea of what the question is about, possibly prompting them to read the question.

Comment: This question isn't about Mathematics, it's about guessing what the question is. 

Comment: Best guess is that OP "knows" (from simulations) that "the minimum of $f(x)$ is the same...", but doesn't know it in the sense of possessing a rigorous proof, and that's what OP wants. Agreed that the question is a little jumbled.

Answer (score 3):

$N=6$, $K=4$, $P=\{1,2,4,5\}$, $x=(1,1,1,1)$, $l=1$ seems to give $f(x)=0$.

There are values of the parameters for which $f$ has no minimum. Take $N=5$, $K=4$, $P=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $x=(a,b,b,a)$, $l=1$. Let $$\theta=\sum x_je^{2\pi il/N}=a(\beta+\beta^4)+b(\beta^2+\beta^3)$$ where $\beta=e^{2\pi i/5}$. Now, $\beta+\beta^4=(\sqrt5-1)/2$, $\beta^2+\beta^3=-(\sqrt5+1)/2$, and these two numbers are linearly independent over the rationals, so there are arbitrarily large $a$ and $b$ for which $|\theta|$ is arbitrarily small. So $$f(x)={|\theta|^2\over4(a+b)^2}$$ can be made arbitrarily close to zero. It can't be exactly zero, since $\beta,\dots,\beta^4$ are linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: Thank You so much for your attention! But l is not arbitrary. If I didn't mention it, that's because I didn't want to put off the readers and I thought it is not important, but seems it is. Let me correct my mistake.

Comment: OK, let's review the bidding. You post a question here and on m.se, without notifying either site until you get caught. The question itself is a dog's breakfast. Despite my repeated attempts here and on m.se to get you to post something comprehensible and complete, you insist on withholding important information. Now, after I take the time to compose an answer, you move the goalposts again. You don't want an answer to your question --- you won't even tell anyone what your question is. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I didn't want to make you angry. My question is not secret! I just wanted to say less to attract more.